# How do I output lines that do not match 'this_string' using Get-Content and Select-String in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, grep

I found a post about users that wanted to use grep in PowerShell. For example,

```
PS> Get-Content file_to_grep | Select-String "the_thing_to_grep_for"
```

**How do I output lines that are NOT `this_string`?**

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Select-String has the `NotMatch` parameter.

```
get-content file_to_grep | select-string -notmatch "the_thing_to_grep_for"
```

Comment: you can of course do it in a single command `select-string -path file_to_grep -notmatch "the_thing_to_grep_for"`

Answer (score 14):

```
get-content file_to_grep | select-string "^(?!the_thing_to_grep_for$)"
```

will return the lines that are different from `the_thing_to_grep_for`.

```
get-content file_to_grep | select-string "^(?!.*the_thing_to_grep_for)"
```

will return the lines that don't *contain* `the_thing_to_grep_for`.

Comment: Sorry, I decided to move the correct/accepted answer to the select-string -notmatch version below. I personally would rather use your regexy version but for the grand majority, I thought that I should move the accepted answer to fit the nature of this platform

Comment: @Chrips: hey, no need to apologize. Manojlds‘ answer is definitely better.

Answer (score 5):

```
gc  file_to_grep | ? {!$_.Contains("the_thing_to_grep_for")}
```

which is case-sensitive comparison by the way.

Comment: Select-String has -CaseSensitive, which can be shorted to `sls -CS`