# Find files which does not contains selected string

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find all files, which does not contains a selected string. Find files which contains is easy:

```
gci | select-string "something"
```

but I do not have an idea how to negate this statement.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm  not sure if it can be done without the `foreach-object` but this works:

```
gci |foreach-object{if (-not (select-string -inputobject $_ -Pattern "something")){$_}}
```

Comment: I would also use the switch `-List`, i.e. `Select-String ... -List` in order to make this more effective, presumably, because we do not need all the found matches.

Comment: And one more thing. This code returns directories as well. In order to avoid this I would use `gci -File` (in PowerShell V3, at least).

Comment: `Where-Object` can make it even simpler. `gci -File | Where-Object {!(Select-String -InputObject $_ -Pattern "something" -List)}`

Comment: I found this "ls . -name yourfile*.txt | where {-not (select-string -path $_ -pattern "stringYouDontLike" -Quiet)}" on  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/b20748b9-57f2-474d-b90f-8d09fcf37fb7/get-filename-that-does-not-contain-the-specified-string?forum=winserverpowershell

Answer (score 28):

You can use `Where-Object`;

```
gci | Where-Object { !( $_ | Select-String "something" -quiet) }
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentionend in [How do I output lines that do not match 'this_string' using Get-Content and Select-String in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214937/how-do-i-output-lines-that-do-not-match-this-string-using-get-content-and-sele)

Select-String has the `NotMatch` parameter.

So you could use it:

```
gci | Select-String -notmatch "something"
```

Comment: My guess is that the downvotes are due to this approach returning every single line in every single file that doesn't match the pattern specified. While I'm sure there's a use case for that, the question is asking for a way to just list the files that don't contain your search pattern, and this approach isn't very helpful for that.

Comment: This will always return `True`. Since there are blank lines in the output of `gci` (a.k.a. `Get-ChildItem`), there will always be lines that do not match the provided pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
 Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {-Not($_.Name.Contains("Case-Sensitive-String"))}
```

In other words:

```
gci | ? {!($_.Name.Contains("Case-Sensitive-String"))}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($line in Get-Content .\file.txt) 
{
    if(findstr $line "dummyText.txt" ){
        # Work here or skip here
    }
    else {
     
      echo $line 
    
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?