# How to create a powershell script / or windows .bat file for ffmpeg

Tags: powershell, batch-file, ffmpeg

So, I want to create a Powershell or Batch file (whichever works best for the task), that I can paste in a folder and after executing it, will start to  use FFmpeg to encode all videos

The part that works (in .bat):

```
for %%a in ("*.mkv") do(
  ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v libx265 -c:a copy -x265-params crf=25 "%%a [encoded].mkv"
   pause)
```

This works, but in some folders, I already have [encoded] files. I'd like for the script to skip these files.
I asked in reddit and received the following script:

```
for %%a in ("*.mkv") do (
if not exist "%%a [encoded].mkv" ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v libx265 -c:a copy -x265-params crf=25 "%%a [encoded].mkv"
pause)
```

I tried the script, but every file got encoded, even if it had the [encoded] in it. After I pointed that out, they told me that I should probably switch to PowerShell and gave a link to a StackOverflow question:

> You probably need to switch to PowerShell
> [Find files which does not contains selected string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945514/find-files-which-does-not-contains-selected-string)
> Then do a foreach in what is returned to execute the ffmpeg command on it.

but I don't know how to code in PowerShell (never used it before)
Would a .bat file even work? If yes, how could I write it? And if a PowerShell script would be the better option, how would I code it?

Any help and answers are appreciated.

Comment: Your issue is probably that your code is using `"%%a [encoded].mkv"`, which would expand to `"SomeName.mkv [encoded].mkv"`, whereas you need, `"SomeName [encoded].mkv"`. The fix for that would be to change it to `"%%~na [encoded].mkv"`. For more information about for variable expansion, please open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the output. From that you should see that `%~n` will expand the variable to its name without extension. I would suggest that pressing  a key, between each iteration is unnecessary, so move the `pause`, outside of the for-loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **PowerShell**, you can use the following (you can paste this code as-is into a PowerShell console window):

```
Get-ChildItem *.mkv | where BaseName -notlike '*`[encoded]' | foreach {
  ffmpeg -i $_ -c:v libx265 -c:a copy -x265-params crf=25 "$($_.BaseName) [encoded].mkv"
  pause
}
```

- `Get-ChildItem *.mkv` uses the [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) cmdlet to get information about all files with extension (`.mkv`) in the current directory (you could add `-File` to explicitly rule out directories, but directory names with extensions are are).
- `` where BaseName -notlike '*`[encoded]' `` uses the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlet (whose built-in alias is `where`) to weed out files whose base name (the name without the filename extensions) already ends in  `[encoded]`. Note the `` ` `` before the opening `[` in order to use it *verbatim*, because `[` has special meaning in PowerShell's [wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards), which the [`-like` / `-notlike` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-like) operates on.
- `foreach { ... }` uses the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet (whose built-in alias is `foreach`) to invoke `ffmpeg` for each file of interest:

  - Inside the script block (`{ ... }`), the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) refers to the pipeline (`|`) input object at hand, which in this case is a [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instance representing an input file.
  - `"$($_.BaseName) [encoded].mkv"` uses an [*expandable string*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (string interpolation) to derive the output file name via the input file's base name (`$_.BaseName`).

Answer (score 1):

`%%a` already is the full filename (including `[encoded]`), so your `if` can't work.
I suggest another approach:

```
for %%a in ("*.mkv") do (
  echo %%a|findstr /iel "[encoded].mkv" >nul || ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v libx265 -c:a copy -x265-params crf=25 "%%~na [encoded].mkv"
  pause
)
```

(I didn't check if the `ffmpeg` syntax is ok - I trust you there)